# php convert string to static variable

Tags: php, class, static-variables

I don't know very good how to describe my problem, but here's what I want to do: 
I want to escape the language variables and convert them to static variables. Something like this

```
public static $languages = array('nl', 'en');
public static $nl;
public static $en;

public function __construct(){
    foreach(self::$languages as $lang){
        self::{$lang} = $content[$lang];
    }
}
```

I know this is possible with a non static variable like this:

```
$this->{$lang} = $content[$lang];
```

but I constantly get errors when trying to convert it to a static variable. 
Is there a way to do this? or is it impossible in php?

Comment: `self::${$lang} = $content[$lang]` should work for statics.

Comment: `__construct()` will not be called for static variables or methods. You are probably looking for a singleton pattern. Is this simply a config storage mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.:

1. A class var must be a constant expression.  An array definition is not.
2. Static vars are accessed with $.
3. `$content` is not defined.

Just for example, this works:

```
public static $nl;
public static $en;

public function __construct(){
    $languages = array('nl', 'en');
    foreach($languages as $lang){
        //self::${$lang} = $content[$lang];
        self::${$lang} = time();
        echo self::${$lang};
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! p.s. $content had been defined, but I just didn't include it in the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot create static variable on the fly in php. You can find the similar response in this thread [Is it possible to create static variables on runtime in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587483/is-it-possible-to-create-static-variables-on-runtime-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

No you cant do this, even using `self::${$lang} = ...` you will get PHP fatal error:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: MyClass::$lang in test.php on line 9

However, are you sure you want to use static property? I assume you pass the `$content` array into the constructor when instantiating the object. If the values inside $content is specific to that particular object, you should stores those values into object properties instead of static properties.