# Enums in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, enums, constants

Before PHP 5.3 I was using the following home-made function to create enums :

```
function enum()
{
    for($enums = func_get_args(), $enum = reset($enums), $i = 1; $enum; $enum = next($enums), ++$i)
    {
        if(defined($enum)) throw new Exception($enum.' is already defined.');
        else define($enum, $i);
    }

} // enum()
```

And then :

```
enum('CONST0', 'CONST1', 'CONST2', ...);
```

With php 5.3 I can do that using const instead of define to benefit from namespaces. Is there a way I could modify this function to make it use the const keyword ?

Also I'm only using 5.3 to make my code look cleaner, if there must be a performance impact (i.e. using eval or stuffs like that), I'll stick with the good old define.

I've already looked at this question : [PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enums) but I didn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you downvote, please at least explain why. This is unconstructive and stupid.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _Is there a way i could modify this function to make it use the const keyword ?_ because this is the only question you ask.

Comment: I don't see what isn't clear in this question. Let me ask it differently : could i use the const keyword instead of the define function inside of this function to create constants that only exist in the namespace where the enum function is called ?

Comment: If you want this it work in namespaces you'd have to create an enum function in all of them.

Comment: Because if a call from namespace A a function in namespace B, when the function will be executed, i will be in namespace B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `const` keyword conditionally [[see this very high voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const)].

If you want to namespace your constants, the best approach is to make them static fields of a class, taking advantage of magic `__get` and `__set` if you needed.

EDIT: no magic setters / getters in static context of course, you can come with a flexible solution anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand now, compile time only for const. The annoying thing with using const is that you manually have to manage the value of the nums : $i = 0; const CONST0 = ++$i; const CONST1 = ++$i; etc... I wanted to avoid this too. EDIT: wait no it doesn't work either, have to hard code 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question: *Is there a way i could modify this function to make it use the const keyword ?*

**Short answer**: no

**Long answer**: Yes you can, but only in an very awkward way:

```
<?php
function enum() {
    for($enums = func_get_args(), $enum = reset($enums), $i = 1; $enum; $enum = next($enums), ++$i) {
        eval('const ' . $enum . ' = ' . $i . ';');
    }
}

enum('CONST0', 'CONST1', 'CONST2');
```

Tested on http://3v4l.org/ontRN

Comment: Yeah i've tought about this, but i think it's not worth the extra performance const. THanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Performance? :-O How many constants do you want to define?

Comment: Well not so many, but i was always told eval is unoptimized and not clean.

Comment: Sorry to say but `enum('CONST0', 'CONST1', 'CONST2');` is not clean at all. Defining you constants one by one is.

Comment: But why would i explicitly show their value using define() if their value does not matter ?

Comment: Because if you one day in the distant future notice, that `CONST1` is no longer needed and remove it all values will change and if any external data relies on this value you will be in trouble.