# What's the difference between define('MENU_IS_ROOT', 0x0001) and define('MENU_IS_ROOT', 1)?

Tags: php, drupal

In drupal|menu.inc, I found the constant was defined in Hexadecimal :

```
define('MENU_IS_ROOT', 0x0001)
```

why not

```
define('MENU_IS_ROOT', 1)
```

==================================

there is another code snippet:

```
define('MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB', 0x0004);
define('MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM', MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB | 0x0010);
```

is it equal MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM = MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB = 16 ?

Comment: The first question is not constructive, but the second question has a definitive answer. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

It's for [bitwise operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

define("FLAG_ONE", 0x0001);
define("FLAG_TWO", 0x0002);
define("FLAG_THREE", 0x0004);
define("FLAG_FOUR", 0x0008);
define("FLAG_ALL", FLAG_ONE|FLAG_TWO|FLAG_THREE|FLAG_FOUR);

function make_waffles()
{
    echo 'Yummy! We Love Waffles!!!';
}

function do_something($flags)
{
    if ($flags & FLAG_TWO)
       make_waffles();
}

$flags |= FLAG_TWO;
do_something($flags);

?>
```

BTW, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const/3193704#3193704) to know when it's better to use const or define.

Comment: your code is easy to understand. thx a lot for give me the key to the question.

Comment: You don't have to define numbers in `0x` format to perform bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

Hex constants are often used for bit masks. When you're defining all the values, it makes it easy to see the bit pattern relationships.

The resulting values are the same, it just makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the results are the same.
I think it's only a matter of personal preference!

Answer (score 0):

> Why not `define('MENU_IS_ROOT', 1)` instead of `define('MENU_IS_ROOT', 0x001)`?

Those are identical; some people just like the idea of hexadecimal values.

> Is `define('MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM', MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB | 0x0010);` the same as `define('MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM', 16);`?

No, `0x0004 | 0x0010` is equivalent to `4 | 16` which equals `20`. It's easier to understand the binary or (`|`) operator when you look at the values in binary:

```
0x0004 = 00000100
0x0010 = 00010000
         -------- OR
         00010100 = 0x0014 = 20
```

Comment: You have an error in "0x0010 = 00001010". It should be "0x0010 = 00010000" instead.