# const PHP Parse error

Tags: php

```
// define('DOCROOT', realpath(dirname(__DIR__)));
// good

const DOCROOT = realpath(dirname(__DIR__));
// PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in
```

why error?

Comment: You should check the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: You're getting an error because that's not how you define constants outside of a class in PHP.

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3193704/42139

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constant can be defined two ways in PHP,

1. Using `const` keyword

   You can't assign the **result of function**, or even a **variable** to  a constant in this way. the value of the constant (defined this way), **must** be a fixed value, like an integer, or a string.
2. Using [**define()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

   in this way, you can assign any value or variable or result of any function to your constant.

***Important note :*** `define()` Works OUTSIDE of a class definition.

### Examples

```
$var = "String"; 
const CONSTANT = $string;                        //wrong
const CONSTANT = substr($var,2);                 //wrong
const CONSTANT = "A custom variable";            //correct
const CONSTANT = 2547;                           //correct
define("CONSTANT", "A custom variable");         //correct
define("CONSTANT", 2547);                        //correct
define("CONSTANT", $var);                        //correct
define("CONSTANT", str_replace("S","P", $var));  //correct

class Constants
{
  define('MIN_VALUE', '0.0');  //wrong - Works OUTSIDE of a class definition.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A class constant has to be a fixed value. Not the result of some function. Only global constants set by `define` may contain results of a function.

Global Constants: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Class Constants: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Sample for a global constant:

```
define("FOO",     "something");
echo FOO;
```

Sample for a class constant:

```
class Test {
    const FOO = "Hello";
}

echo Test::FOO;
```

Comment: This is completely wrong.  You can define a constant to be whatever value you want.

Comment: No. Only if it is a static value that is fixed during compile time.

Comment: Youre right, this rule is only applicable to class cnstants, not global ones. tested and confirmed. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

`const` definition must be inside the scope of one class.

Comment: There are global constants and there are class constants. Two different things.