# Is there a way to define constants that persist in memory when PHP loads?

Tags: php

Is there a way to define constants that boot into memory when the PHP process starts on the server? If so, can it be done with arrays, classes, and functions as well?

Before people start listing the different ways of declaring things that will be available across pages and scopes: I'm **not** asking this from a coding convenience, but rather a performance perspective.

It seems like a waste to keep loading things that never change, from pages or databases etc, on every script execution. Being a server-side process, I would think PHP has some way to read things into memory once and have them always available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an *opcode cache*. Opcode caches work by storing the compiled contents of PHP files in shared memory, then using that data to short-circuit the standard code parsing process when the file is included/required in the future.

The canonical opcode cache at this point is the [PHP opcache extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php), but a number of other opcode caches exist, including [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) and [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/).

Opcode caches do not cache data from databases. There are other extensions which you can use to assist in this process, though, such as [APCu](http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) which stores them in shared memory, or [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) which stores them in an external process. None of this is automatic, though, as caching data from a database requires some application knowledge to know what is useful to cache, and to handle cache invalidation when you update the database.

Comment: Just wanted to note some things I learned when looking into this: Opcache is included in PHP 5.5+, and available for PHP 5.2+ by installing the Zend Opcache extension (which I had to do, and it's now running). Even in 5.5+, it needs to be explicitly enabled. Opcache doesn't do exactly what I asked in the question (I asked about sending selected things to memory), but it does something better -- it compiles and caches ALL PHP scripts to memory. Thanks duskwuff :)

Answer (score 1):

In general php is a single treaded environment and it does not actually run constantly (unlike java). Php starts working only when receives a command to do so. Then it parses the code into opcode and eventually executes it. And that technically happens on every request (or CLI command).

However, there are several ways how you can cache the opcode with not much efforts with APC: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php