# Which one is efficient define() or Class CONST to keep site/application wide configuration constant in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.4, php-5.6

I like to know which one of the below is efficient to declare site/application wide configuration in PHP.

1. `define()`
2. class `CONST` variable.

Comment: I got the perfect answers to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const/3193704#3193704

Comment: can i delete this question @saty