# PHP: undefined constant while defining it

Tags: php, undefined, constants

I'm getting the following error in PHP:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant CONSTANT

on the exact line where I define it:

```
define(CONSTANT, true);
```

What am I doing wrong? I defined it, so why does it say "Undefined constant"?

Comment: `define('CONSTANT', true);`

Comment: You can't define CONSTANT, it's just that; a CONSTANT - RTMs  http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const/3193704

Comment: @TomasZubiri It's not a duplicate of that question; I did not seek for the difference between define vs const, I was asking what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to quote the string which becomes a constant

```
define('CONSTANT', true);
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to understand what are you doing wrong is to read PHP manual.

Here is definition of [**define**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function.

```
bool define ( string $name , mixed $value [, bool $case_insensitive = false ] )
```

So the first argument must be a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you write it like that you are using the value of an already defined constant as a constant name.

What you want to do is to pass the name as a string:

```
define('CONSTANT', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Although not really, strictly relevant to your case, it is most desirable to first check that a `CONSTANT` has not been previously defined before (re)defining it.... It is also important to keep in mind that ***defining `CONSTANTS` using `define` requires that the `CONSTANT` to be defined is a `STRING` ie. enclosed within Quotes*** like so:

```
<?php

    // CHECK THAT THE CONSTANTS HASN'T ALREADY BEEN DEFINED BEFORE DEFINING IT...
    // AND BE SURE THE NAME OF THE CONSTANT IS WRAPPED WITHIN QUOTES...
    defined('A_CONSTANT') or define('A_CONSTANT', 'AN ALPHA-NUMERIC VALUE', true);

    // BUT USING THE CONSTANT, YOU NEED NOT ENCLOSE IT WITHIN QUOTES.
    echo A_CONSTANT;  //<== YIELDS::   "AN ALPHA-NUMERIC VALUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

See below currect way to define constant

```
define('Variable','Value',case-sensitive);

Here Variable ==> Define your Constant Variable Name
Here Value ==> Define Constant value
Here case-sensitive Defult value 'false', Also you can set value 'true' and 'false'
```