# Why DEFINE in PHP can accept random values?

Tags: php, constants

Constants can't accept expressions that make calculations. Why can I declare DEFINE with random_int(1,4) and not get a fatal error? In this case, the value of the constant will be different every time the page loads. Is this correct for the ideology of constants?

```
define('RANDOM_NUMBER', random_int(2,4));
```

It's ideology question. Why is this correct in PHP? And why can use the expression in DEFINE but not in constants?

Comment: why do you think it can not be expression?

Comment: Because `define` is executed at runtime. First, the expression is evaluated, then assigned to the constant. Where’s the problem?

Comment: Constants are meant to be constant for a single invocation of a script, not every invocation ever made of it.

Comment: You define it as the number that is generated. Not different than define('RANDOM_NUMBER', 3). The random number is calculated before it gets defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [define() vs const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const)

Answer (score 1):

> Constants can't accept expressions that make calculations.

This is not true.

`define` may accept as second parameter expressions, included values returned from a called function.

The restrictions for the `value` parameter of define are (from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php))

> **value**
>
> The value of the constant. In PHP 5, value must be a scalar value (integer, float, string, boolean, or NULL). In PHP 7, array values are also accepted.

---

Of course a constant cannot be defined twice.

And -if I understand your question- this is the "*ideology*" of constants.

As they are defined the value cannot be modified in another part of the script as it's **constant**.

Of course if the script is run a second time the constant can get a different value like in your case.

---

Worth mentioning this is different for [**Class Constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) - constants you declare inside a class definition with the keyword `const`.

Due to language design/specifications

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.

Comment: I meant the const in the class when said that they can't accept expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `define` function only get the result of `random_int(2,4)` as parameter and has no way to understand if it was created in a random or in a deterministic way.

What the program really does is:

```
$temp = random_int(2,4);
define("RANDOM_NUMBER", $x);
```

That said, the define is used to define a constant for a request script, not necessarily a constant for all requests, so it does make sense that every different request has a different value for the defined constant.

Answer (score 0):

The official php documentation states:

> While it is possible to define resource constants, it is not
>   recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior.

The same will apply to any non scalar values assigned to a DEFINE constant. The PHP documentation states that:

> The value of the constant. In PHP 5, value must be a scalar value
>   (integer, float, string, boolean, or NULL). In PHP 7, array values are
>   also accepted.