# Is there a magic constant in PHP like __DIR__ but with unresolved symlinks?

Tags: php, symlink, magic-constants

Everything is in the title.

I am trying to write an app in php with client and server features.
For testing purpose (at least), I need several clients. To not have to copy the written code, I thought using symbolic links.
Something like this : My main "repository" is `MyClient/scripts`
I create near `MyClient` a `MyClient2` folder in which I create a symbolic link to be able to use all the scripts of `MyClient` for `MyClient2`

```
ln -s ../MyClient/scripts scripts
```

At the really beginning of my scripts I am allowed to create some `const`  using `__DIR__`.
I found a lot of workaround to get the value I am looking for from variables (for example : `$_SERVER['PWD']`) but this doesn't allow me to define a `const`.

So I am looking for a constant just like `__DIR__` but with unresolved symlinks.

This gives the result with resolved symlink (not what I want)

```
<?php 
const mydir = __DIR__ ;
echo mydir;
?>
```

This throws a Fatal error (not what I want)

```
<?php 
const mydir = $_SERVER['PWD'] ;
echo mydir;
?>
```

**EDIT**
This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const). My question doesn't involve `define` at all, while the linked one is explicitly asking for how it works. For my question `define` has been suggested as a workaround which good enough regarding my need.

Comment: define("mydir", $_SERVER["PWD"]);

Comment: I feel ashame. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: No worries. Im not hunting points... Just glad i could help.. :)