# What is the best files between txt or php in read php

Tags: php

I would know what is the best between this element to charge information (speed) ?

```
test.php
define('HEADING_TITLE', 'Groups');

test.php
const HEADING_TITLE = 'Groups';
```

`const > define` : sur on that (speed)

`txt > const` : what do you think ?

Comment: **WHAT?????** Have another try at asking the question whatever it is

Comment: [const is faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2458276/4233593)

Comment: Who gives a flying duck about saving a nanosecond in that particular case?

Comment: If this you're at the level of performance where this is your biggest concern, you must have a very impressive system

Comment: As others have said, this doesn't matter, as any speed difference will be meaningless. Much better to find the *real* bottlenecks (function calls, DB queries, etc.) that actually take up time